# Combine two queries as a single one

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Description**

- select maximum tert value as max and minimum tert value as min where
  iner between 43 and 79 and apply formula (max+min)/2+min as reip
- select the tert where iner nearer to 45 as r45 and
- select the tert where iner nearer to 72 as r72 Apply Formula

**Formula**

```
700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r45)*40
```

output value as repw
and i want to display reip value and repw value as output

I tried it in PostGreSQL

```
Select (MAX(tert)+MIN(tert))/2+MIN(tert) as reip from table_name where iner between 43 and 79
```

This is working but i dont know to apply this reip value in 700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r40)*40 in this formula and how to get the ouput value display as reip and repw

I tried this query it's not working..

```
select reip, 700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r45)*40 as reipw
from ( 
  select (MAX(tert)+MIN(tert))/2+MIN(tert) as reip, tert where iner=44.5 as r45, tert where iner=71.9 as r72
  from  table_name
  where iner between 650 and 800
) as SE_23693370
```

How to execute the task as a single query? Anyone guide me...

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do with "select (MAX(tert)+MIN(tert))/2+MIN(tert) as reip, tert where iner=44.5 as r45, tert where iner=71.9 as r72". I think you are trying to do case statement.

Comment: I doubt this as in where clause we have "iner between 650 and 800" so case statement will always return null.

Comment: @Ambrish I apply this Formula **Select (MAX(tert)+MIN(tert))/2+MIN(tert) as reip from table_name where iner between 43 and 79** and its output as reip this reip value should be applied into this formula **700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r45)*40** and display both reip & reipw. I tried case staqtements also it is showing error statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query a bit like below

```
select reip, 
(700+(reip-r45))/((r72-r45)*40) as reipw
from ( 
  select (MAX(tert)+MIN(tert))/2+MIN(tert) as reip, 
  case when iner=44.5 then tert end as r45, 
case when iner=72.1 then tert end as r72
  from  table_name
  where iner between 43 and 79
  group by iner,tert
) as SE_23693370
```

Comment: @user3640530, while posting error be specific to the query posted in answer. don't post a random error from different query. that confuses more rather helping. Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: @user3640530, see your fiddle updated http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0ad8f/13. If you have a separate question, open a separate post instead clubbing with this post.

Comment: Sir, Your Query is working but it is showing so many values on reip row and no value display on reipw row, according to my question, the output will be two values only. one reip value and one reipw value for table data. Sir i'm trying still, i dont know whats the problem...

Comment: @user3640530, no offense but I think it's time you should learn about SQL. why are you getting those `null` in reipw column is left as homework to you. Hint: validate the data present in your table and you will find it.